# Reserve/Hold extra money in paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am gonna develop a hotel reservation site in which i have integrated paypal payment gateway. I wanna hold some additional money from user in respect of "If a person will reserve my hotel then it will have to pay some additional amount for the damages. if the user will not cause any damage to my hotel paypal will return this amount otherwise any damage occurs the money will not be returned to user. it will be paid to me". What is the paypal method that i can use in this scenario.

Comment: you can use future payments technique of paypal

Comment: any reference url plz

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_mobile.md

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md

Answer (score 0):

One common way to implement this kind of functionality is to use "Auth/Capture". In this case you initially Authorize an amount you want to charge and then at a later point in time you Capture (actually take) that amount of money, or a smaller or larger amount, or completely cancel it.

Note, although you don't actually receive the money until you Capture the payment, the end-user is usually unable to access that amount once it has been authorized.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/